# Why call connect function without mapStateToProps or mapDispatchToProps as args?

Tags: react-redux

In one of the Redux examples from the docs the connect function is called with no args. This can be seen at the bottom of the example.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'

let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
let input

return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      if (!input.value.trim()) {
        return
      }
      dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
      input.value = ''
    }}>
      <input ref={node => {
        input = node
      }} />
      <button type="submit">
        Add Todo
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
 )
}

AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

From my understanding the purpose of the connect function it to give container components access to actions dispatchers in the form of callbacks aswell as access to state from the store in the form of props.

Therefore it doesn't make sense as to why you would call connect without specifying the state and action creators that you want to give the component access to.

Comment: `connect()(AddTodo)` will pass `dispatch` as a prop, which is still useful even without state or predefined actions

Comment: Thanks. Why would we want to pass dispatch as a prop when we can just call it as a method on store and import the store?

Comment: created an answer, hopefully it addresses this

Comment: Are there any other benefits to avoiding explicitly passing down the entire store apart from convenience?

Comment: not passing the entire store down is less convenient then just passing the the whole store everywhere, but then you're potentially mixing concerns all over the place. generally speaking components are explicit about what props they get, and only take what they need. again this is an architectural decision that is not specific to redux, but to your apps needs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`connect()(AddTodo)` will pass `dispatch` as a prop to AddTodo component, which is still useful even without state or predefined actions.

Redux (and react-redux) is a pretty low-level library. It allows you to be very strict about what state and actions a component has access to, or you can pass the entire store and every action to every component, and everything in between.

It's up to you to decide what level of strictness is appropriate for your application.

Why use `connect` at all, you may ask? Well `connect` just passes store / dispatch through React context so you don't have to pass the store through many components. You don't *have* to use `connect` though. Any module / HOC pattern could work, `connect` just happens to be a convenient thing to use.

Comment: if connect has parameters , dispath will be passing yet ?

Comment: @DDave `dispatch` gets passed passed as a prop to the wrapped component with or without arguments. is that what you are asking?

Comment: If you `connect()` without args, doesn't redux still implement its optimizations with `shouldComponentUpdate()` for you? It would do a shallow equals on the props (in this case just `ownProps`) to see if it should render right? It's better than the default `true` for `shouldComponentUpdate().