# Proper use of react-redux connect

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm new in react-redux and I was reading the documentation here https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md
The documentation says that `connect` is defined as:

> connect([mapStateToProps], [mapDispatchToProps], [mergeProps], [options])

But then I see this example code

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getData } from '../actions'

class Content extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

   componentWillMount() {
      this.props.dispatch(getData())
   }

   render() {
      const { data } = this.props; //This data is the same returned for fungetStore

      return (
         <div>
            <h1> { data.text } </h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

const fungetStore = store => {
   return {
      data: store  //Return the content of the store
   }
}

Content = connect(fungetStore)(Content)

export default Content
```

You can see in the code that the `fungetStore` is sent in connect. But why connect is used in this way? It's not supposed that you must define `mapStateToProps` and/or `mapDispatchToProps`?. There is something in the documentation that I'm missing out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why call connect function without mapStateToProps or mapDispatchToProps as args?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044121/why-call-connect-function-without-mapstatetoprops-or-mapdispatchtoprops-as-args)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names of the parameters to `connect` are `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.  They're frequently referred to as `mapState` and `mapDispatch`, but you can call your functions anything you want.

In this example, `fungetStore` is an example of a "mapState" function.  It doesn't matter whether it's called `mapStateToProps`, `mapState`, `fungetStore`, or `fred`, it's a function that receives `state` as an argument and is being passed as the first parameter to `connect`.

Also, each of the parameters to `connect` are optional.  All of these are valid:

```
connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(MyComponent) // use state and dispatch actions via functions
connect(mapState)(MyComponent)              // use state
connect(null, mapDispatch)(MyComponent)     // dispatch actions via functions
connect(null, null)(MyComponent)            // dispatch actions via dispatch()
connect()(MyComponent)                      // dispatch actions via dispatch()
```