# ComponentWIllReceiveProps not getting called unless page is refreshed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am building a react native application but I noticed that `componentWillReceiveProps` is not getting called as soon as I dispatch some actions to the redux store, it only gets called when I refresh the screen.

**Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { renderLogin } from '../../components/Auth/Login';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    const { navigate } = props.navigation;
    if (props.userData.authenticated) {
       navigate('dashboard')
    }
  }

  login = () => {
      renderLogin()
  }
  render() {
      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
          <Container style={styles.home}>
            // Some data
        </container>
        )
      }
   }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return {
        userData: state.auth
     }
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen)
```

**RenderLogin**

```
    export function renderLogin() {
      auth0
        .webAuth
        .authorize({
          scope: 'openid email profile',
          audience: 'https://siteurl.auth0.com/userinfo'
        })
        .then(function (credentials) {
          loginAction(credentials)
        }
        )
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
```

**loginAction**

```
    const store = configureStore();


    export function loginAction(credentials) {
      const decoded = decode(credentials.idToken);
      saveItem('token', credentials.idToken)
      store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    }

    export async function saveItem(item, selectedValue) {
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(item, JSON.stringify(selectedValue));
        const decoded = decode(selectedValue);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
      }
    }
```

Comment: How do you dispatch actions?

Comment: @HuyVo I have modified the code.

Comment: I mean how do you dispatch your action in `HomeScreen`? I didn't see any code where you dispatching.

Comment: @HuyVo IIf you look through my code I have a login method, when a user is authenticated. a token will be returned which I stored in AsynStorage then dispatch the actions. I can verify that the redux store gets updated but componentWillReceiveProps is not getting called inside the HomeSCreen component.

Comment: There're a lot of missing code, for example where do you use `getToken` in the code above? What is the code of `renderLogin`? Provide the full context and maybe we can help. Also adding redudant imports (Container, Text, Button,..) is kinda distracting you know.

Comment: @HuyVo Thanks for your response, I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem has something to do with `mapStateToProps`, i.e. when you have updated your state in redux but not yet map the new state to your props, therefore props in `HomeScreen` will remain unchanged and `componentWillReceiveProps` will only be triggered once.

Have a read on [Proper use of react-redux connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946749/proper-use-of-react-redux-connect) and [Understanding React-Redux and mapStateToProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202572/understanding-react-redux-and-mapstatetoprops).

Comment: The component is connected so I think by default it should subscribe to any changes in the redux store.

Comment: What improvement do you suggest to fix this issue?

Comment: I thought my answer was clear: you need to map your state from redux store to your component as props (see my edit).